# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.10 (port 3100) from /192.168.0.13 (port 50964) after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

I was developing an app where I have a http server in my computer which I call from a kotlin app, and I getting an error which rise the moment I try to interact with API clases.

My server is this, which is running on my computer:

index.js

```
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3100);
app.use(bodyParser.text({type:"*/*"}));
app.post('/',function(req, res){
    console.info("===== Request received! =======\n" + req.body + "\n=================================");
    try {
        const result = processRequest(req)
        console.info("===== Response =======\n" + result + "\n=================================");
        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        res.status(200);
        res.send(result);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error("Response error: " + ex.message)
        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        res.status(500);
        res.send(ex.message);
    }
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.info('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

function processRequest(req) {
    const body = req.body;
    if (!body || !body.startsWith("<")) {
        throw Error("Invalid XML body or missing body")
    }
    if (body.includes("<LoginRequest>")) {
        return `<LoginResponse>
        <RespCode>00</RespCode>
        <RespText>Approved</RespText>
        <SessionID>000381</SessionID>
        </LoginResponse>`
    }
    if (body.includes("<GetCheckInfoRequest>")) {
        return `<GetCheckInfoResponse>
        <RespCode>00</RespCode>
        <RespText>Approved</RespText>
        <CheckInfo>
        <CheckNum>123</CheckNum>
        <PaymentDue>1295</PaymentDue>
        </CheckInfo>
        <CheckInfo>
        <CheckNum>124</CheckNum>
        <PaymentDue>1325</PaymentDue>
        </CheckInfo>
        </GetCheckInfoResponse>`
    }
    if (body.includes("<PostPaymentRequest>")) {
        return `<PostPaymentResponse>
        <RespCode>00</RespCode>
        <RespText>Approved</RespText>
        <PaymentDue>0</PaymentDue>
        </PostPaymentResponse>`
    }
    if (body.includes("<DisconnectRequest>")) {
        return `<DisconnectResponse>
        <RespCode>00</RespCode>
        <RespText>Approved</RespText>
        </DisconnectResponse>`
    }
    throw Error("Unknown message, not supported")
}
```

And regarding the flow of login is the folowing:

LoginScreen.kt

```
   var employeeId by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    var shopNumber by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    var terminalNumber by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val loginResponse by viewModel.loginResponseDTO.collectAsState()
    val showDialog: Boolean by viewModel.showDialog.collectAsState()
    val errorMessage: String by viewModel.messageDialog.collectAsState()

PayAtTheTableTheme {
        Surface {
            if (showDialog) {
                SimpleAlertDialog(
                    context = context,
                    show = true,
                    title = context.getString(R.string.titleError),
                    text = errorMessage,
                    onConfirm = viewModel::onDialogConfirm ,
                    onDismiss = viewModel::onDialogDismiss,
                    elevation = 10
                )
            }
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding((width / 20).dp)) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted),
                    contentDescription = "Settings",
                    Modifier
                        .clickable { navController.navigate(Screens.Settings.route) }
                        .align(Alignment.End)
                        .size(Utils.convertPixelsToDp((width / 6).toFloat(), context).dp)
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo_paytef),
                    contentDescription = "logo",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .fillMaxHeight(0.2f)
                )
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = shopNumber,
                    label = { Text(text = context.getString(R.string.numberShow)) },
                    onValueChange = { shopNumber = it },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )

                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = employeeId,
                    label = { Text(text = context.getString(R.string.idEmployee)) },
                    onValueChange = { employeeId = it },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = terminalNumber,
                    label = { Text(text = context.getString(R.string.terminalNumber)) },
                    onValueChange = { terminalNumber = it },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))

                FloatingActionButton(
                    onClick = {
                        val loginRequest = LoginRequestDTO(
                            storeNo = shopNumber,
                            deviceNo = terminalNumber,
                            userID = employeeId
                        )
                        try {
                            viewModel.login(loginRequest, context).also {
                                if(loginResponse?.respCode == "00"){
                                    //TODO: Change to keep into ViewModel creating a State
                                    loginResponse?.sessionID?.let { sessionID -> viewModel.setSessionId(sessionID) }
                                    viewModel.setEmployeeId(employeeId)
                                    viewModel.setShopNumber(shopNumber)
                                    viewModel.setTerminalNumber(terminalNumber)
                                    navController.navigate(Screens.Dashboard.route)
                                }else{
                                    viewModel.showDialog(context.getString(R.string.textError))
                                }
                            }
                        }catch (e:Exception){
                            e.message?.let {msg ->
                                viewModel.showDialog(msg)
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(text = context.getString(R.string.enter))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SharedViewModel.kt

```
  private val _loginResponseDTO: MutableStateFlow<LoginResponseDTO?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val loginResponseDTO: StateFlow<LoginResponseDTO?> = _loginResponseDTO.asStateFlow()    

fun login(loginRequest: LoginRequestDTO, context:Context) {
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                loginUseCase.login(request = loginRequest).also {
                    loginUseCase.loginResponseDTO?.let {
                        _loginResponseDTO.value = it
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _messageDialog.value = e.message ?: context.getString(R.string.textError)
            _showDialog.value = true
        }
    }
```

LoginUseCase.kt

```
@ActivityRetainedScoped
class LoginUseCase @Inject constructor(private val payAtTAbleApi: PayAtTableApi){
    //private var _loginResponseDTO: MutableStateFlow<LoginResponseDTO?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    var loginResponseDTO: LoginResponseDTO? = null

    suspend fun login(request: LoginRequestDTO) {
        payAtTAbleApi.login(request).also { call ->` //crash the moment enter on this method
            if (call.isSuccessful) {
                loginResponseDTO = call.body()
            }else{
                throw Exception("Login failed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the API:

```
    @Headers(
        "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    )
    @POST("/")
    suspend fun login(@Body loginRequest: LoginRequestDTO? = null): Response<LoginResponseDTO>
```

Regarding my AppModule, where I build the Retrofit client is this:

```
    @Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {
    private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()


@Provides
    fun providePayAtTAbleApi(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences): PayAtTableApi {
        return ApiClient(
            baseUrl = if(sharedPreferences.getString("url_pay_at_table", null) != "") "http://${sharedPreferences.getString("url_pay_at_table", null)}" else{"https://www.google.com"},
            converterFactory = SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(),
            okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient
        ).createService(PayAtTableApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

As I said, looks like although the server say is runnig the moment useCase method try to call the API, crash.

The logcat doesn't return me any exception, so I cannot debugged correctly, I make me guess the problem perhaps is on the server side.

I add a picture from debugg before crash in LoginUseCase:

[image]

[EDIT]

So after several testing I'm able to get some logcat message, which indicate is a problem of connection between my server and my app:

Please notice that the 192.168.0.10 is my computer acting like a server, and the 192.168.0.13 ip is my terminal, where I launching the app.
I don't know if is can be due to some segurity check I'd have to disable, or firewall.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 Process: es.paytef.payattable, PID: 23447
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.10 (port 3100) from /192.168.0.13 (port 34914) after 10000ms at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185) at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:357) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616) at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.kt:63) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

If can help take thanks on advance !

[EDIT]

I add my AndroidManifest.xml configuration to allow http conections:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PayAtTheTable"
        android:name="es.paytef.payattable.MainApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name="es.paytef.payattable.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.PayAtTheTable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and regarding network_security_config file is this:

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Where is your app running?

Comment: You are running a http server but you did not tell us.

Comment: `13 ip is my terminal, where I launching the app. ` ? Please explain. Dont understand a word.

Comment: My app is running on a payment device which run on Android, and the server is running on my computer. Those ip is where are running each: 192.168.0.13 and 192.168.0.10. I update the question, due to you are right, it's confussing

Comment: And you use http protocol and http:// urls? What is Android version on device?

Comment: `getting an error which rise the moment I try to interact with API clases.` ? I think you get that socket timeout exception when your app tries to connect to te server: when it does a http request.

Comment: i'm using http://192.168.0.10:3100 as my url, due to my server is listen on that port (3100). And regarding the last question: " getting an error which rise the moment I try to interact with API clases": That right.

Comment: Sorry, but if you are using a http server then the client should use http:// urls. Unless your client implements the http protocol itself using just a socket. Unclear what you are doing.

Comment: It's what it's using. The full url of the server is "http: //192.168.0.10:3100"

Comment: Ok. Then i wait until you answer my other question(s).

Comment: Regarding your other question I guess I should use the http: url, due to i'm not using sockets, but Retrofit libraries. Nevertheless, i'm already settinng 'http:' as root of the url, following by the ip

Comment: Please read my comments. You did not answer all questions.

Comment: I try to answer. The Android version is Android 13, and yes, i'm using an http server which is the index.js, so as I say I'm using htp:// urls, being "urls" the ip of each device. If there a question i'm missing, please let me know

Comment: All is answered. What did you do in manifest file to enable http protocol?

Comment: I edit my answer adding manifest and network_securuty_config.xml file

Comment: Ok. Sorry then i dont know what goes wrong.